# Why might doxygen fail to generate expected UML output?

Tags: doxygen

I have access to two machines with doxygen setup and working. On one it produces nice boxed uml diagrams, on the other, it outputs something like unrendered `dot` diagram code. I've tried the same working config on both, and reset to a clean config but can't seem to change the behavior.

No errors are reported in the doxygen output and I've tried to enable debug logging but no output is ever written to disk. Both `doxygen -d extcmd -d plantuml` and `ENABLED_SECTIONS = debug` fail to produce a log file.

**Actual**

[image: Actual Output]

**Expected**

[image]

**Problem Environment**

- dot/graphviz 5.0.0 (0)
- doxygen 1.9.5
  [image]

**Working Environment**

- dot/graphviz 2.43.0
- doxygen 1.9.1
- docker container Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

**Notes**

If I knew more about doxygen, plantuml, and dot I might be able to look at the output below and picture which step along the execution pipeline failed, or which step produced output that caused the failure. At a glance I'd think plantuml produced the result I see in the image and dot failed to render it. When I try to type the literal text seen in the image, or at least a concise subset of it, dot errors out on the pipe character. However, maybe dot isn't playing a part in rendering the file. All I can say for sure is something succeeds a producing the image file on disk, they just don't render it into the expected box format.

[image]

Comment: You mention "I have access to two machines with doxygen setup and working. ", are they both have the same doxygen version and the same dot version? (I don't think so). There has been a problem in doxygen resulting in the problematic output.

Comment: The environment which produces good results is an older version of doxygen 1.91 with dot-graphviz 2.43.0, in a docker container. The reason for the inclusion of the detail was to help illustrate that in at least one case, I had a good doxygen config file that produced a working UML result. In the problem environment, the default config and that working config file both produce output that looks like `dot` failed to render, and I have failed in my troubleshooting steps to identify why. Very grateful for any help on the issue.

Comment: The problem is due to some recent changes in doxygen but, by head, it should work again in the 1.9.6 version of doxygen (so an update the 1.9.5 version would be needed).

Comment: Excellent to know. I'll assume there are no manual steps to work around the issue on 1.9.5 and investigate if we can downgrade or come up with some other solution in the near term. Thanks!

Comment: I would not downgrade but upgrade to 1.9.6

Comment: Regarding the "Notes" you wrote: The problem has nothing to do with plantuml. The problem was in the doxygen usage of dot in respect to the usage of node types "box" and "record"